# Http get + NgFor

Tags: angular, http, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve datas from a webservice (JSON result) and render it in a Angular 2 component with `*ngFor`. Here is my datas :

```
{
  "Columns": [
    {"Label": "CodeProduct"},
    {"Label": "productfamily_ID"},
    {"Label": "description"}
  ]
}
```

And here is my Angular component :

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response}  from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.html'
})
export class AppComponent
{
    columns: Array<Object> = [];

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProducts()
            .subscribe(
            (columnRemote: Array<Object>) => { this.columns = columnRemote});
    };

    private _url = 'api/data/product';

    getProducts() {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
            .map((res) => res.json().Columns);
    }
}
```

And my template :

```
<h3>Hello StackOverFlow</h3>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#column of columns">{{column.Label}}</li>
</ul>
```

I can see that the title appears, but not the list of my columns (even if I try with a static string, like 'Test' inside the `<li>`). If I fill my array with static values in the constructor, I can see the array displayed.
In the debuger I can see that datas are correctly retrieved, but in this line :

```
.subscribe((columnRemote: Array<Object>) => { this.columns = columnRemote});
```

the variable *this* is of type *Subscriber* and not of type *AppComponent*. Is that normal ? Do I've done it wrong ? I'm working with Angular2 beta6 with ES5 TypeScript.

**EDIT** 1 : Here is what debuger show me for `res.json()`

[image]

Comment: from the code above , I am thinking you are getting an object,but you are treating like array.try `<li *ngFor="#col of obj.Columns">...</li>`

Comment: I'm treating like an array because I return the columns array in the .map function : `.map((res) => res.json().Columns);`

Comment: got the issues bro..working on it

Comment: Check the network tab, and see what data is returned. If that's okay, check what's returned from the `res.json()` function call. To see if there is actually a property named `Columns`

Comment: Of course the datas are here. See my edited question. It's only (I think) when I try to assign the result array to my component array. Can ES5 be a problem for that in the .subscribe method ?

Comment: Have you added `angular2-polyfills.js` to your `index.html`?

Comment: OMG it worked ... !!! I spend so much time for this ... Can you post a response with an explanation ? I'm very curious about that ....

Comment: `angular2-polyfills.js` includes `zone.js` that is used by angular to kown when to update data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to let angular know when to update data, add `angular2-polyfills.js` to your `index.html`, because this will include `zone.js`

(thanks @lucacox)

With the correct order of adding the libraries is:

`es6-shim.min.js`

`system-polyfills.js`

`angular2-polyfills.js`

`system.src.js`

`Rx.js`

`angular2.dev.js`

Be aware that the necessary libraries may change over time as angular2 is maturing. Always check the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) guide, when you update to a newer version of angular2.

Comment: Nice ! One more question : why `system-polyfills.js` and `es6-shim.min.js` ?

Comment: These are Internet Explorer polyfills. IE requires polyfills to run an application that relies on ES2015 promises and dynamic module loading. Where `es6-shim` supplies the ES2015 promises, and `system-polyfills` the dynamic module loading